# String to Date Parsing not working

Tags: java, string, date, parsing

I am getting date as string as a parameter from Servlet.
Now when I am trying to parse it again to get `util.Date`, it gives me error.

I am getting string `"Fri Jul 02 00:00:00 IST 2010"` & I want `util.Date` from it.
Tried `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat` but didn't work.

Comment: Please post the exact code you tried, and the result you got from it. Without that, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Please edit the question and add: What error do you get? What format pattern did you use?

Comment: DateFormat is not broken; provide some code and a stack trace please. And have you read SimpleDateFormat's API docs?

Comment: You need to give the SimpleDateFormat object the correct pattern string. See here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact date format of your string-represented date is:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

But I would suggest on configuring your custom format, and use it for converting back and forth.

Comment: I think that should be `HH:mm:ss` instead of `hh:mm:ss`: `HH` is hours in the format 0-23, `hh` is 1-12. There's no AM/PM indication in the string.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you set the format of your date string, it should work:

[Parsing a date using a custom format](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/parsedate.html)

My guess is that you don't have the SimpleDateFormat string set properly.  Try starting with a simple date String (dd/MM/yyyy) and seeing if you can get that to work.